# Forms Authentication with SSL - Is my app secure?

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, ssl, encryption

I was recently asked to change the authentication method of an existing application using Windows authentication to Forms authentication against Active Directory.

What was new to me was the need to use SSL only on the login page.

1. By looking at many articles including [this one](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;813829), it says to use the Encrypt method when creating the authentication ticket. My question is, doesn't `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` method create an encrypted cookie? So, why the need to manually create the authentication ticket?
2. I've been looking at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7206/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically-Ver) great article on how to switch between http and https. However, my code needs to be as less intrusive as possible, so this can be easily merged later in production. So, is it correct to use absolute paths instead in the web.config file?

   `<authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="https://localhost/Login.aspx"
          defaultUrl="http:/localhost/Default.aspx"/>
    </authentication>`
3. Due to the fact that the app will be switching between http and https, it's not possible to use attribute `requireSSL=true`. What other measures should I consider besides encrypting the cookie using `proection=All`?
4. Is there any risks in leaving the Active Directory connection string visible? Should this be encrypted?

Comment: why would you want to switch between https and http? If you have a valid certificate then you might as well use it for the entire site

Comment: You can use HTTPS for your entire site. The only issue is a heavier workload in your server, but depending of the use it may be not too much.

Comment: @musefan: Companies like facebook don't ;-) I assume the reason being is less processing (there is a "cpu tax" on decrypting incoming data). **EDIT** I stand corrected--fb uses https throughout. Must have changed that when I wasn't looking because it used to be only the login page was https.

Comment: @BradChristie, that is 100% accurate. By having a certificate installed you can simply send data over a secure channel by changing the protocol (e.g. `http` to `https`) and so it's much more efficient to use `http` when you're not sending sensitive data.

Comment: @neoistheone, the problem with using http is that if you have users logged in, their authentication cookie will be sent in the clear, allowing an eavesdropper easy access to their account. That's why so many services have moved to https only.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick responses. The reason why is that as this app was not developed by us, and is therefore not entirely known, the client is afraid that moving to https only might affect the behaviour of some components